# Partial Obfuscation C code

Tags: c, obfuscation

I have a big project to share, with several files and linked libraries. My collaborators will need to modify some specific functionalities. Is there any way I can partially obfuscate the non development-needed  areas of the code?

Comment: Organise your codebase such that the parts which your collaborators should not need to modify can be presented to them in compiled and linkable form, leaving only the parts to be modified available in source form.  Would that suffice ?

Answer (score 0):

If the functionalities you mentioned, are in form of functions you can provide function pointer type definitions in your header, and let the user register their own functions. You should also add a Register_Func() function to your header.
This function modifies the static pointers to these functions.

in your header:

```
typedef void (*myfunc_p)(int);

void Register_Func(myfunc_p F);
```

Then in your code:

```
static myfunc_p   Modified_Function;

void Register_Func(myfunc_p F)
{
  Modified_Function=F;
}
```

Then you can only share a DLL, along with your header. And they can register their customized code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how messy it gets. I'd just create an API that expose the functionalities they need and provide them with the source code they want to modify as a separate library. This way they'll only see the prototypes (and you can obfuscate these with dummy parameters) and any source code examples. That way, for the most part, supply them the .dlls or .so files for them to build against. If they keep asking for more code it might be time to openly refuse.

BTW, if this is a collaboration then you don't have to give them anything but if they've commission you to do some work they may have rights to access all your code if it hasn't been stipulated otherwise. So check your agreement you mightn't have a choice.

In truth if you're using something like C (and a code base of say less than 10,000 lines) it doesn't take much to disassemble code and reverse/back engineer. A good assembly programmer wont have much problems here. Compiling with optimisation will make it slightly more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Since we will all be working with VS, I deleted the source code and added the obj files. It is working.